# How to merge folders and subfolders?

Tags: command-line, filesystem

I have two folders (ORIGINAL A and ORIGINAL B), and both do have subfolders.

How do I merge these two folders (and subfolders) to DESTINATION C?

a) ORIGINAL A and ORIGINAL B do have the same subfolders. I want to copy every unique file of any subfolder into the "correct" subfolder of DESTINATION C

b) some subfolders are only in ORIGINAL A, but not in ORIGINAL B. I want any folder in DESTINATION C

Does anyone know a terminal command?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try:

```
rsync -aP /ORIGINAL_A/* /DESTINATION_C/
```

This is like a copy of the folder A

```
rsync -aP /ORIGINAL_B/* /DESTINATION_C/
```

That should sync the folders A an B to another the new folder C.

You could sync the file from A to B directly but you don't will have data loss this way.

Comment: thx dude, you made my day. This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: What to do if rsync is not available? How to do it with CP?